# Are ‘säen’ and ‘sehen’ homophones?

Tags: verb, pronunciation

I am wondering if the absence (or presence) of the *h* affects pronunciation in this particular case. My intuition is that they should be pronounced the same way. I found some online pronunciations and they do sound the same to me. Am I correct?

The second question is how *sät* is pronounced (as in *ihr sät*). Is it pronounced exactly as is written, or does the pronunciation of the infinitive (the unwritten *h*) affect it in any way? Are *ihr seht* and *ihr sät* pronounced differently?

Comment: Well, there's more than just the absence/presence of "h". There is "ä + e"  versus "e + e". So, the first syllables "sä" and "se", respectively, are already pronounced different, disregarding what's following them.

Comment: What pronounciation site did you use? A good resource for (official) pronounciations is DUDEN online: 
Go to [säen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/saeen) and click the *speaker symbol* in the section *Aussprache*. The same for [sehen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sehen).

Comment: @Iris: It was a big news to me that these letters can be pronounced differently. Anyway, I do hear the difference from your links, but it's still hard for me to reproduce them. I guess I'm jumping ahead of myself. With time...

Comment: Regarding the role of _h_, note that _sehen_ and _Seen_ (‘lakes’) are homophones. It really only serves to indicate that the vowel is long in these cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, *säen* and *sehen* are distinct in many dialects. The vowel in both verbs is long. Long *e* is rendered as [e:] while long *ä* is rendered as [ɛ:] in many dialects thus providing a clear distinction. You *would* have been correct if the verbs had short vowels. Short, stressed *e* is pronunced [ɛ], exactly like short, stressed *ä*.

Furthermore, *sehen* is an irregular verb whose vowel stem vowel changes in parts of the present tense (*du siehst*) and the past tense (*ich sah*). But even in forms with the unmodified vowel (*ich sehe*) is the vowel quality distinct from that of *säen*. *Säen* in the present tense always retains the same (long) vowel quantity as expected from the lack of a double consonant. And the participles (*sehend/sähend; gesehen/gesät*) retain the long vowels and thus the differentiation, too.

However, not everywhere are the distinctions between long *ä* and *e* kept. Especially in the North, the pronunciation of *Käse* as ['ke:zə] is prevalent (compare standard ['kɛ:zə]). These dialects would have difficulties distinguishing between the two.

---

Note on pronunciation: The [ɛ] sound is more open than the [e] sound. They can be compared to French *è* and *é*, respectively. Unfortunately, English pronunciation is too unregular for me to come up with examples right now.

Answer (score 6):

No, they are pronounced differently.

The reason, though, is not the "h", but the fact that "ä" and "e" are pronounced differently, although casually spoken language, especially regional accents or even dialects, may make them sound similar or even identical.

The "official" pronounciations, though, are distinct.

[EDIT] after the clarifications @HubertSchönalst gave (thank you!):
The above is mostly valid for Germany. Apparently, in Austria the opposite is the case.

Please regard "official pronounciation" as the way a professional news reader or similar would pronounce the words.

Comment: »ä« und »e« werden nicht überall unterschiedlich ausgesprochen. In Österreich werden ä und e (bis auf wenige Ausnahmen) gleich ausgesprochen. »Bären« und »Beeren« klingen in Österreich genau gleich. Auch der Sämann (der, der Getreide aussät) und der Seemann (der auf der See rumschippert) werden bei uns genau gleich  ausgesprochen. Und in »Wir werden ja sehen, ob man bei dem Wetter säen kann.« werden die fraglichen Wörter auch gleich ausgesprochen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast i must admit that my point of view is german, and i tend to see austrian pronounciation as a local accent or dialect. Is there something like an "official austrian pronounciation" in the same sense as there is a Duden version for germany?

Comment: Es gibt weder für deutsches Deutsch noch für österreichisches Deutsch (das übrigens kein Dialekt, sondern eine der drei Standardvarietäten der deutschen Sprache ist) verbindlichen Ausspracheregeln. Daher stehen im Duden auch keine solchen Regeln. Im übrigens ist der Duden kein verbindliches Nachschlagewerk der deutschen Sprache. Das von der österreichischen Bundesregierung herausgegebene Österreichische Wörterbuch hingegen schon, allerdings nur für österreichisches Deutsch. Aber auch dort stehen keine Ausspracheregeln (weil es nun mal keine gibt).

Comment: Aber es gibt die Adaba (**A**ussprache**DA**ten**BA**nk) http://www.adaba.at die für viele Wörter die österreichische, deutsche und schweizerische Aussprache, jeweils von einem Mann und einer Frau gesprochen, in Form kleiner Audio-Clips bereithält. Leider ist diese Datenbank nicht vollständig (»sehen« ist vorhanden, »säen« leider nicht) Aber das Wort »L**e**berk**ä**se« ist vorhanden, und dort hört man, dass die beiden fett hervorgehobenen Vokale in Österreich genau gleich gesprochen werden.

Comment: Die sechs Sprecher, die man in der Adaba hören kann, sind übrigens vom Berufs-Sprecher, zumindest gilt das für die beiden österreichischen Sprecher, das sind nämlich beides ehemalige Nachrichtensprecher des Österreichische Fernsehens.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast besten Dank! Wieder was gelernt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast http://forvo.com has entries for [säen](http://forvo.com/word/säen/#de). There's one Austrian guy and one German guy and I cannot really hear a difference between them (in respect to the "ä") and it sounds exactly as what I'd expect, namely with an "ä", i.e. not "e". Unfortunately, only German pronunciations for "sehen".

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Zumindest der männliche Sprecher aus Österreich macht einen klaren Unterschied in _Leberkäse_. Auch die Lautschrift gibt an, daß das _ä_ offener gesprochen wird, wenn auch weniger offen als ein [ɛ].

Comment: @chirlu: Ich gebe zu, dass Peter Fichna (der männliche österreichische Sprecher) den dritten Voakl in [ˈleːbɐˌk**eː**sə] eher als eine Mischung aus [eː] und [ɛː] ausspricht, als ein reines [eː]. Aber vergleiche die österreichische und die deutsche Aussprache von *w**ä*hrend*, ***ä**chten*, ***ä**hnlich*, ***Ä**ther* oder ***e**nth**ä**lt*. Dann wirst du erkennen, dass das »Ä« (bis auf wenige Ausnahmen) in Österreich anders ausgesprochen wird als in Deutschland.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Die Frage ist nicht, ob es anders als in Deutschland ausgesprochen wird, sondern ob es eine Opposition zwischen /eː/ und /ɛː/ gibt, wie auch immer die Laute dann realisiert werden. Das scheint mir der Fall zu sein (mit /ɛː/ als [e̞ː]); das ist bei _Leberkäse_, _während_, _ähnlich_ und _Äther_ jeweils der Fall. (_Ächten_ und _enthält_ sind nicht einschlägig, weil der Vokal darin kurz ist.) Leider ist die phonetische Transkription nicht 100% zuverlässig, wie man etwa am Eintrag _enthält_ sieht, wo die Betonung durchgehend falsch angegeben ist.

Comment: In large parts of the German speaking area, both in the north and in the south, *ä* in this context is usually pronounced exactly like *eh*. However, there is an awareness of the difference that is kept alive by the different spellings. Professional speakers everywhere will pronounce them differently, and almost everyone everywhere will do so when trying to resolve an ambiguity. Learners of German should therefore try to pronounce the vowels differently.

Comment: There is a very similar phenomenon in French. Traditionally and in careful speech, *je ferais* is pronounced with the same final vowel as *progrès*, corresponding to German *ä*, and *je ferai* is pronounced with the same final vowel as *blé*, corresponding to German *eh/ee*. But nowadays most people pronounce both like *ä* - except for professional speakers, teachers in dictations and people trying to resolve ambiguities.